# Running Ardor3D as Applet

Tags: java, applet, ardor3d

I am trying to build a small applet that provides some 3d functionality into a website, and i have selected Ardor3D as it seems to tick the boxes. I have just started going with Java, and everything I have learnt so far has been from the examples files which has been enough to this point. The program is distributed by a JNLP file, that downloads the classes and defines how it starts, but I was wondering how to run it as an applet, so the 3d image output would be displayed in its rectangle at its position in a web browser window?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ardor3D has examples of running as an applet.  Your game code will be the same as when running as a standalone app, but you extend an applet class instead.  See for example the [LwjglBoxApplet](http://ardorlabs.trac.cvsdude.com/Ardor3Dv1/browser/trunk/ardor3d-examples/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/example/applet/LwjglBoxApplet.java).

Comment: Rather use this example at the one above has been removed from JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation: https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D/blob/master/ardor3d-examples/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/example/applet/JoglBoxApplet.java

Comment: The link above is dead as Renanse stopped the maintenance of Ardor3D in March 2014 and applet support will be removed from JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation soon: https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D/issues/22